# Java Map Implementation not based on HashCode

Tags: java

Is there some implementation of `java.util.Map` that does not uses HashCode?

I have the following problem:

1. I store an object associated to another object on a HashMap;
2. Change a property from the key object used on step 1;
3. As the hashcode is used to store the keys on the regular implementation of HashMap, when I perform a `get()` on the `HashMap`, I get null, because the old object hashCode was different at step 1.

Is there a solution for that? Or should I really use just immutable fields for my equals / hashCode methods?

Comment: How would the hashmap know that you just changed its internal key? Remove and reinsert or don't use mutable keys to begin with.

Comment: this wasn't my idea... my target is use a impl that just uses the equals instead of hashmap, even if is not optimized

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IdentityHashMap uses the Object identity instead of the hashCode; however that does mean that you require the original object used as key to retrieve the value of the map. Other options would be redefine the hashcode to exclude the mutable parts of the object, or - if you can't redefine the hashCode for some reason - wrap the object in another object which provides a stable hashCode.

Answer (score 9):

You would be well advised to use an immutable key, and to re-insert the key/value pair into Map, rather than mutating the key in-place.  As you discovered, that just leads to weird bugs.

If this isn't an option for you, then see if you can ignore the mutable property in the `hashCode()` method, so that the hash code doesn't change. If that's the only property of the class, though, that's not a good idea.

You *may* be able to get away with using `TreeMap`, which I don't *think* uses `hashCode()`. However, it does require consistency between the key's `compareTo()` and `equals()` methods, so you may just end up with the same problem as before if the return values of those methods can change.

Comment: FYI, if the compareTo implementation is also dependent on the mutable field then you can get the same results with a treemap.  equals, compareTo and hashCode should all be constant (in their behavior) over the lifetime of the object.

Comment: @luke: Yes, I believe I said that.

Answer (score 2):

*All* Maps should use immutable objects for keys.  True for Python; true for Java.

If you implement equals and hashCode using only immutable fields you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

All associative containers use comparing or hash code, so I would like to recommend you using immutable fields for `equals() / hashCode()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

How about removing and adding it again ?

On Step 2, You can remove the element added in Step 1 and again add it with new latest properties set. This way when you are try to get in Step 3, you will find it.

Try it.

Comment: Although this works, I also think it clearly demonstrates a flaw in the design. Other objects or logic should not need to be aware of these kinds of implementation details and workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I think modify the key object in map is not a good practice.

But if you really want, you can override the `hashCode()` and remember to override the `equal()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Override `equals` and `hashCode` methods if you don't want original implementation.